# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy 6.0.1 - ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES - System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, .net, asp.net-core

I get the following error when trying to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy 6.0.1` NuGet on start:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
> Connection id "X", Request id "Y:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
> application.
> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
> at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Context
> context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
> application)

In .NET 5 the following code was provided in `Startup.cs`.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

This is not present in .NET 6, instead `launchSettings.json` has an environment variable: `"ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"`

I know it works since a new project using template `ASP.NET Core with React.js` and .NET 6 starts without a problem.

What is needed to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy` to an existing.NET 6 ASP.NET Core application with Create React App project with TypeScript?

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

I have tried to add the files `aspnetcore-https.js`, `aspnetcore-react.js`,`.env`, `.env.development` from working project.

Edited `Program.cs` with these values:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

Modified `package.json` to look like this:

```
"prestart": "node aspnetcore-https && node aspnetcore-react",
"start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
```

I have installed `rimraf` and the command `npm run start` and `npm run build` works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This specific error needed a variable called `SpaProxyServerUrl` in `.csproj`. A few other things were required to get everything to work as expected so complete code below:

`launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39330",
      "sslPort": 44358
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Project.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7178;http://localhost:5178",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

`.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-Project.Web-12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012</UserSecretsId>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44358</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)build\**" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
            <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
        </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: To whom it might concern. If the client still won't start, please check that your selected profile in launchSettings.json, does not have a "launchUrl" entry. That seems to prevent it from running.

Comment: +1 Awesome, thanks! It is nice that C# now supports "script" style programs - but honestly I don't think they should have changed it for the webapi samples.

Comment: Thanks for this. I almost had it.. was missing one line `"ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"` in the Project setting.. Now the fun part.. building this and deploying as one docker image 

Comment: @PiotrKula have you ever gotten a docker image to work with this?

Comment: @cmxl yes I have. The only trouble is doing SSL certificates your self on a Linux based docker. You can install nginx-proxy-manager though which is really cool because it has an automatic letsencrypt feature. But getting the image started needs a bit massaging. I have API and SPA bundled into one image and use SignalR between them. Works like a charm. If you got an issue open a new question and ping me. I will gladly help out

Comment: My SpaProxy solution is working.  However, what is the easiest "launchsettings" changes I can make to have the solution behave like a production deployment? In other words, I want a launchsetting where the SPA is built and hosted as static files...without the use of the SPA dev server.  I want that for the sake of testing something closer to a real production environment.

Comment: How is <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44358</SpaProxyServerUrl> supposed to work in production? What changes are needed when one publishes to Azure?